# Is there a way to recognise and execute code after a click() event has finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I am programmatically clicking a button, which when done, will show a dialogue on the page.

I want to modify the dialogue after it has been fully loaded, because part of the code following the click modifies the dialogue.

This is achievable with function with timeout, but I am exploring a way that would not use a set timeout, but rather monitor when that click action is complete.

Note: 
1. I cannot modify the code which is executed on button click.
2. I need to achieve a solution which is not time based, as this could vary, although not much, is still something i would want to avoid.

Sample code below tha works - enough time is allowed for click to finish

```
function modifyDialogue() {
    $("#dialogue").click();
    setTimeout(function() { 
        $("#scrollBar").remove();
    }, 30);
}
```

Sample code that doesnt work - not enought time for scrollBar to be rendered. ScrollBar renders based on the length of text inside dialogue. But since time is not enough, the removal does not happen.

```
function modifyDialogue() {
    $("#dialogue").click();
    $("#scrollBar").remove();
}
```

Comment: Depending on the dialogue, you probably can listen for a `loaded` or `shown` event that the dialogue throws.

Comment: You can use callbacks.

Comment: What dialogue are you using? As mentioned most have events you can listen to

Answer (score 0):

Edited: This no matter when it loads will hide the scroll bar.

```
function modifyDialogue() {
    $("#dialogue").click();
    $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
}
// Alternate
$( "button" ).on( "click", function() {
  $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

Comment: This is happening already and with a small timeout 30ms, which so far has not failed even once. I am just trying to look for a solution without using any timeout functions if possible. Something to monitor that all executions based on that click have finished and then safely I could do the next part, which is removing the scrollBar. Also, as mentioned above, I do not have access and i cannot modify the code which happens on click, out of my power. If I had access there, then the story would be different.

Comment: Ah, so you can't create an event listener, something the user is doing calls the function which calls the click method correct? There is still a way if so.

Comment: Do you have a code pen, Is there a reason the scroll shouldn't be hidden before the dialog appears. Maybe I can understand what you are trying to do because it seems like a simple solution.